# resign as director from / of the board

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Jet Airways' power couple Naresh Goyal and his spouse Anita Goyal on Monday resigned as directors **from** the board of the company.

Shouldn't there be "of" instead of "from" preceding the board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but they have different structures, and so at least potentially different meanings.

Since *resign* normally takes a *from* argument, the sentence as printed must mean

> ... resigned (as directors) from the board ...

If you use *of*, it must have a different structure:

> ... resigned as [directors of the board] ...

In this case, I don't see much difference in meaning, but in other cases the difference could be significant.

I find the first to be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may resign *as* chairman, member, president, etc. *from* membership, position, post, seat, etc.

If the position they occupied was (as in your sentence) director of the board of the company, they resign *as* director of the board (and may stay with the company, taking some other position), or resign as director of the board (of the company) *from* that company (and leave it).

In other words, the verb *resign* does collocate with *from* and *as*, and don't with *of*.

[The source](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/resign).

As for your sentence, I dare to suggest rephrasing it as

> ...they resigned from the company as directors of its board.

As a side note, since the noun *board* (in the context provided) means a group of people who are responsible for controlling and organizing a company or organization, each one of this group may be called director, i.e. a person in charge of an organization or of a particular part of a company’s business. Thence, the "as directors" part seems to be redundant, and the sentence may be shortened to

> Naresh Goyal and his wife Anita Goyal resigned from the board of
>   Jet Airways on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

"Director of the Board" is a standard noun phrase. So is "member of the Board of Directors" with an essentially identical meaning.

> [They] resigned as directors from the board of the company.

is perfectly grammatical and idiomatc. So is:

> He resigned as a Director of the Board [of XYZco].

So is

> He resigned from the Board of Directors.
>
> He resigned from his position on the Board of Directors.

is a bit more formal. So is:

> He resigned from his position as a Director  [of XYZco].

The form:

> They resigned from the company as directors of its board.

and other versions including "resigned from the company" seems to me to imply that the person/people resigning had been employees, which board members usually are not, and which was apparently not the case here.

One can "resign as {title}". One can resign "from {position}A" or "from {group}".

Answer (score -1):

Here, you have to think about where the prepositional phrase references. It references the verb **resigned**. So the word **from** is more correct. A good way to check this is to remove **as directors** and see if the flow of the sentence remains in tact.

> Jet Airways' power couple Naresh Goyal and his spouse Anita Goyal on Monday resigned from the board of the company.
>
> Jet Airways' power couple Naresh Goyal and his spouse Anita Goyal on Monday resigned of the board of the company.

The second sentence sounds awkward using **of** twice.

Comment: They might resign as directors of the board (a committee having supervisory powers) of the company, yet stay with the company as some other officials, say, the board members,

Comment: Then, they would resign as directors of the board from the company. Either way, using ***of*** twice here sounds awkward.

Comment: They resigned from the company as directors of its board. Does this sound okay?

Comment: "A good way to check this is to remove as directors". Maybe, but "as directors" seems to be part and parcel of the question. Besides, to resign as... from... is a valid collocation.

Comment: It is just checking for flow. as directors is an adverb statement using a subordinating conjunction, in reference to resigned. Just breaking down the sentence to its core to check for non-awkwardness.

Comment: To resign of a job/office is just invalid collocation, and it's all I want to say..

Comment: Correct. I agree.